# Paste data on specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

Giving me error on code line that refers to cell where to paste the data from origin sheet - cell A10, sheet "debtors report". Can someone please help?

```
Sub filetering_kam() 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("debtors report").Visible = True

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW DATA FILE")
.Range("$A$1:$N$5000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Sheets("main").Range("f11")
.Range("b:n").Copy
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("debtors report")
    .Range("a10").Select
    .Range("a10").Paste
    .Range("d8") = Sheets("main").Range("f11")
    .Range("h8") = Sheets("main").Range("c6")
    .Range("a:m").WrapText = False
    .Range("A:M").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Range("a10:m5000").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    .Visible = False
    .Range("A1:N5000").AutoFilter
    End With
```

Comment: What's the error? Which line of code triggers it?

Comment: Thank you Cindy Meister, all good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy entire column then you must paste it to somewhere in row 1, i.e. cell A1, you can't paste it to A10 if you copy entire column.

Also there's no Paste command, you can use PasteSpecial, for example

```
Range("YourDesiredCell").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

for example in your case try to change this line

```
.Range("b:n").Copy
```

to

```
.Range("b1:n50000").Copy
```

then this line

```
.Range("a10").Paste
```

to

```
.Range("a10").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```